# rewrite rule match all or nothing

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't handle one `ReweriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^thingsy_things_(.*)(_in_)?.*?/?$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

**URL:** `www.mydomain.com/thingsy_things_name_name_in_somewhere/`

but sometimes it could be: `www.mydomain.com/thingsy_things_name_name/`

That name part could be `name_name_name` or more.

Perfect delimiter is *in* but in case of `(_in_)?` rule matches everything in first group.

How to handle that?

Thanks!

Comment: if found, would you want to match `name_name_name` or `name_name_name_`?

Comment: I mean to say, do you also want to match the leading underscore if found?

Comment: Without last underscore will be easier but I could always trim that last one in code actually.

Comment: Also, the `name_name` part will consist of one word repeated zero or more times with underscores, correct? For eg: `www.mydomain.com/hello_there_rep_rep_rep/` where `rep_rep_rep` should be extracted

Comment: name_name from one _hello_there_name_in (or without _in_) 
to couple more _name_ occurencies.

You got the clue!

Comment: I apologize, but I don't quite seem to understand. From `hello_there_name_in_something`, shouldn't you be extracting just `name` instead of what you have written - `name_name`?

Comment: Another clarification - Please post the desired results for the following: `www.mydomain.com/hello/`, `www.mydomain.com/hello_there_abc_abc`, `www.mydomain.com/hello_there_abc_abc_abc_in_something`, `www.mydomain.com/hello_there_in_in_something`

Comment: Please answer each sample input respectively, and note that I've not used the term `name` anywhee, but these might be the inputs you receive.

Comment: Are you still active?

Comment: 1. abc_abc
2. abc_abc_abc
3. situation won't exist for sure, there's no chance to "\_in\_" in names part

Comment: do thingsy_things_ same in all requests?

Comment: yes

'samething_othersamething_names_othername_ormorename_in_anytyhing'

clear? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this out:

```
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9]+)(_$1)+)$ /$1 [NC, L]
```

**Note -** I have zero experience in URL Rewriting, but I've tried to understand the syntax, along with my prior knowledge of regex, to give you this code. Feel free to point out my mistakes or any detrimental practices that I may have used.

## Explanation -

`^(([a-z0-9]+)(_$2))+$` is the pattern which checks for the `name_name` format,

`([a-z0-9]+)` is group(2), which captures the `name` part of the `name_name` format,

`(_$2)+` is a backreference to group(2) which means that the `name` part must be followed by one-or-more `_name`s.

Comment: Thanks...but no. 
I can catch my names. Problem is with '_in_' part. 
If it's not there then everyhing is ok. But if it's in the URL and the rule looks like '(_in_)?' (could be, or not) then previos group which catch my names catch also that '_in_' part.

Comment: @vitavision Your comment is not clear, could you please edit your question with at least 5 - 6 sample inputs and outputs?